# linux не правильно работает python скрипт, если стартует как сервис. при ручном старте все ok

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, shell

Народ help, уже всю голову сломал.

Вообщем стартует сервис который запускает file.sh из него стартует file.py - при таком варианте работает не привильно. Если запускаю просто изь консоли python3 file.py - все гуд. Что не так работает, ну например subprocess.getstatusoutput("rocm-smi -d") - это не сработает, если скрипт не запущен из консоли, нужно полностью указать адрес файла, но с некоторыми программами и командами не работает даже с полным адресом. Повторюсь, если запустить из консоли все работает, на серваке не работает.

Comment: При старте из сервиса переменные окружения никогда не содержат всего того, что содержат в обычном сеансе в консоли. Переменная PATH наверняка не содержит всех путей. Рабочий каталог так же может оказаться другим. Явно устанавливайте рабочий каталог и PATH такими какими они нужны для работы. Может еще какие переменные придется подстраивать

Answer (score 2):

Это проблема с некорректной работой скрипта до боли мне знакома

Суть в том, что запускать `python` скрипт через `root` - это **очень плохая идея** (а по умолчанию он так и включается через сервисы)

В качестве решения Вам нужно добавить пользователя себе в сервисный конфиг

```
[Unit]
Description=%название%
After=network.target
 
[Service]
Type=simple
User = %ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ%

Environment=PYTHONPATH=%ПУТЬ ДО ПАПКИ%
WorkingDirectory=%ПУТЬ ДО ПАПКИ%
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 %ПОЛНЫЙ ПУТЬ СКРИПТА%
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
 
[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

Так скрипт должен выполняться как сервис при этом поднимая себя, в случае, если он отключится

Comment: Environment=PYTHONPATH=%ПУТЬ ДО ПАПКИ%
WorkingDirectory=%ПУТЬ ДО ПАПКИ% одновременно не нужно